# R reorders data when changing bar color. How do I prevent this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I have a dataset which I want to draw as bars.
However, R re-orders my dataset as soon as I add colors!

```
library("ggplot2")

data <- read.csv(file = "data.csv",
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# This is what I want position-wise
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(y=median,x=backend)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=generic), position = position_dodge2(padding = .2), alpha = 0.75) +
  labs(title="Median", y="", x="Backends",fill="Generic")
print(plot)

# This is what I want color-wise
anydsl.plot <- ggplot(data, aes(y=median,x=backend)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=ifelse(generic, "Yes", "No")), position = position_dodge2(padding = .2), alpha = 0.75) +
  labs(title="Median", y="", x="Backends", fill="Generic")
print(plot)
```

The dataset is as follows:

```
backend,median,minimum,maximum,generic,threads
cpu,8.70,8.40,14.06,1,1
cpu,8.10,7.65,13.23,0,1
cpu,5.77,5.54,10.04,1,2
cpu,5.42,4.24,9.34,0,2
cpu,4.44,4.12,7.07,1,3
cpu,4.26,3.79,6.82,0,3
cpu,3.70,3.52,6.42,1,4
cpu,3.77,3.48,6.04,0,4
cpu,3.49,3.20,5.40,1,5
cpu,3.53,3.08,5.45,0,5
cpu,3.42,3.08,5.23,1,6
cpu,3.51,3.20,4.79,0,6
cpu,3.46,3.17,4.84,1,7
cpu,3.48,2.98,4.75,0,7
cpu,3.46,3.14,4.76,1,8
cpu,3.47,3.12,4.60,0,8
avx,4.49,4.47,8.85,1,1
avx,4.33,4.31,8.53,0,1
avx,3.58,3.27,6.10,1,2
avx,3.49,3.25,5.99,0,2
avx,3.38,2.97,5.36,1,3
avx,3.40,3.01,5.31,0,3
avx,3.43,2.98,4.62,1,4
avx,3.38,2.84,4.72,0,4
avx,3.40,2.93,4.60,1,5
avx,3.42,2.95,4.53,0,5
avx,3.43,2.97,4.49,1,6
avx,3.42,2.80,4.47,0,6
avx,3.46,3.06,4.49,1,7
avx,3.45,2.91,4.50,0,7
avx,3.46,2.98,5.18,1,8
avx,3.47,2.98,4.42,0,8
cuda,3.04,2.98,3.10,1,1
cuda,0.33,0.32,0.34,0,1
nvvm,3.40,3.33,3.46,1,1
nvvm,2.72,2.68,2.77,0,1
opencl,3.04,3.00,3.09,1,1
opencl,0.33,0.32,0.34,0,1
```

The output without my custom colors is:
[image: 1st print(plot) output]

The output with my custom colors is:
[image: 2nd print(plot) output]

How do I get the first plot but with the colors of the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by mapping `ifelse(generic, "Yes", "No")` on `fill` you implictily change the grouping variable. To get the same grouping as in your first plot map `backend` on the `group` aes

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table(text = "backend,median,minimum,maximum,generic,threads
cpu,8.70,8.40,14.06,1,1
cpu,8.10,7.65,13.23,0,1
cpu,5.77,5.54,10.04,1,2
cpu,5.42,4.24,9.34,0,2
cpu,4.44,4.12,7.07,1,3
cpu,4.26,3.79,6.82,0,3
cpu,3.70,3.52,6.42,1,4
cpu,3.77,3.48,6.04,0,4
cpu,3.49,3.20,5.40,1,5
cpu,3.53,3.08,5.45,0,5
cpu,3.42,3.08,5.23,1,6
cpu,3.51,3.20,4.79,0,6
cpu,3.46,3.17,4.84,1,7
cpu,3.48,2.98,4.75,0,7
cpu,3.46,3.14,4.76,1,8
cpu,3.47,3.12,4.60,0,8
avx,4.49,4.47,8.85,1,1
avx,4.33,4.31,8.53,0,1
avx,3.58,3.27,6.10,1,2
avx,3.49,3.25,5.99,0,2
avx,3.38,2.97,5.36,1,3
avx,3.40,3.01,5.31,0,3
avx,3.43,2.98,4.62,1,4
avx,3.38,2.84,4.72,0,4
avx,3.40,2.93,4.60,1,5
avx,3.42,2.95,4.53,0,5
avx,3.43,2.97,4.49,1,6
avx,3.42,2.80,4.47,0,6
avx,3.46,3.06,4.49,1,7
avx,3.45,2.91,4.50,0,7
avx,3.46,2.98,5.18,1,8
avx,3.47,2.98,4.42,0,8
cuda,3.04,2.98,3.10,1,1
cuda,0.33,0.32,0.34,0,1
nvvm,3.40,3.33,3.46,1,1
nvvm,2.72,2.68,2.77,0,1
opencl,3.04,3.00,3.09,1,1
opencl,0.33,0.32,0.34,0,1", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

# This is what I want color-wise
anydsl.plot <- ggplot(data, aes(y=median,x=backend, group = backend)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = ifelse(generic, "Yes", "No")), position = position_dodge2(padding = .2), alpha = 0.75) +
  labs(title="Median", y="", x="Backends", fill="Generic")
print(anydsl.plot)
```

[image]